# Choosing variables to create when initializing classes

Tags: python, class, variables, constructor, args

I have a class which would be a container for a number of variables of different types. The collection is finite and not very large so I didn't use a dictionary. Is there a way to automate, or shorten the creation of variables based on whether or not they are requested (specified as True/False) in the constructor?

Here is what I have for example:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self,a=False,b=False,c=False):

        if a: self.a = {}
        if b: self.b = 34
        if c: self.c = "generic string"
```

For any of a,b,c that are true in the constructor they will be created in the object.

I have a collection of standard variables (a,b,c,d..) that some objects will have and some objects won't. The number of combinations is too large to create separate classes, but the number of variables isn't enough to have a dictionary for them in each class.

Is there any way in python to do something like this:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self,*args):

        default_values = {a:{},b:34,c:"generic string"}

        for item in args:
            if item: self.arg = default_values[arg]
```

Maybe there is a whole other way to do this?

EDIT:

To clarify this a class which represents different type of bounding boxes on a 2D surface. Depending on the function of the box it can have any of frame coordinates, internal cross coordinates, id, population statistics (attached to that box), and some other cached values for easy calculation.

I don't want to have each object as a dictionary because there are methods attached to it which allow it to export and modify its internal data and interact with other objects of the same type (similar to how strings interact with + - .join, etc.). I also don't want to have a dictionary inside each object because the call to that variable is inelegant:

```
print foo.info["a"]
```

versus

```
print foo.a
```

Thanks to ballsdotball I've come up with a solution:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, a=False, b=False,c =False):

        default_values = {"a":{},"b":34,"c":"generic string"}

        for k, v in default_values.iteritems():
            if eval(k): setattr(self,k,v)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary?

Comment: Because then you would have to call the value via the dictionary in the class, then the key like: foo.d["a"] vs. foo.a

Comment: I mean, why don't you just make `foo` a dictionary? What purpose does your class serve aside from storing data?

Comment: The class also has methods attached to it. At this point it's a question of why do we EVER have classes instead of dictionaries

Comment: If your class does nothing but store properties, it *probably* can be replaced with a named tuple or a dictionary.

Comment: I edited my the question to make my intention clearer. Basically it's a matter of elegance and functionality.

Comment: So are you basically initializing it with `foo(True, False, True)` and the flags determine which variables are set? Do you use positional arguments at all, or just keyword arguments? Are the default values all immutable (no lists, dicts, etc.), or are there mutable types in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

    default_values = {a:{},b:34,c:"generic string"}
    for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
        try:
            if not v is False:
                setattr(self,k,default_values[k])
        except Exception, e:
            print "Argument has no default value.",e
```

But to be honest I would just put the default values in with the init arguments instead of having to test for them like that.

*Edited a couple times for syntax.

Comment: If I place the default value in the constructor arguments then the variable will be created with the default value. If specified as False, or not at all I don't want that variable to even exist in the object

Comment: I see.  Is there any reason why the above wouldn't work then?  It essentially just takes all of the names of the arguments and attempts to set them to their default value.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, but I'm not entirely sure what it does. I will try to understand it and get back to you.

Comment: ok, you would call this something like: my_class = MyClass(a=0,b=0)
i've edited the above to add a check for "False" to behave more like your code.

Comment: I see. It's not exactly what I wanted but it works for this purpose. I've updated my question with something else I put together.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `dict` (if you aren't using positional arguments):

```
class Test(dict):
    def your_method(self):
        return self['foo'] * 4
```

You can also override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` if the `self['foo']` syntax bothers you:

```
class Test(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return dict.__getattr__(self, key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        return dict.__getattr__(self, key, value)

    def your_method(self):
        return self.foo * 4
```